# Where can I find a large list of primes for an array literal?

Tags: c#, arrays, primes

I need a way to store and very efficiently retrieve the first 3512 primes in C#.  As far as I know I would use an int array.

I have not been able to find a comma-separated listing of the first 3512 primes.  What can I do to find/create such a list to paste in for the array, other than rolling my own prime generator?

Comment: take a look on these algorithms http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms

Comment: I remember stumbling onto an awesome website with a repository of numbers and matrices for use in numerical methods and computations. I have lost the link though.. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating 3512 would be fairly easy and quick, but you can find lists pretty easily.  Here's [a list of the first 50,000 primes](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/primes.htm) that would be easy to import or read in.

Comment: It's not comma-separated.  I know it's easy, and I was looking for a really quick solution.

Comment: @jnm2: comma, tab, space: where's the difficulty?

Comment: @mitch-wheat: I was just looking for a copy and paste list that fits the formatting of a C# array, e.g. { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 }

Comment: @jnm2: It would be easy enough to copy-paste that list into an editor and do a find/replace to insert the necessary commas.

Comment: You're right.  I was just hoping.  I did find what I wanted here: http://rlrr.drum-corps.net/misc/primes1.shtml